# Do you use "for" or "on" in this example?

Tags: prepositions

I have a question concerning the use of prepositions.

Could you say:

"We went to the restaurant for mother´s day."

meaning "to celebrate Mother´s day" or should it simply be "on Mother´s day"?

People do say: "I bought this for her birthday" or "...for Christmas", don´t they?

To say "for Mother´s day" seems to be wrong as in "Repeat this for four times!" instead of "Repeat this four times!",but I am not sure about.

Comment: If you're talking about 'restaurant' then it's very clear that you're going to celebrate it. It often gives the meaning of celebration. For example: I am buying some balloons for mother's day. This also indicates the same that I am gonna celebrate mother's day. For more clearance, context is very necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence "... for Mother's day" implies the reason you are going there because of Mother's day (perhaps to celebrate).

Changing the sentence to "We went to the restaurant on Mother's day" implies only that you were at the restaurant during Mother's day.  However, you may/may not have been there because it was Mother's day.  (Perhaps you retrieved your forgotten cell phone---lost on the day before Mother's day---at the restaurant.)